# 1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: ground

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, collision-detection

im asking this question because im trying to make a working collision detection in my platforming game, im using the method that this tutorial uses: http://as3gametuts.com/2012/01/08/platformer-3/

Here is the part of the code that wont work:

```
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);

function loop(e:Event):void
{
    if (ground.hitTestPoint(borat.x + leftBumpPoint.x,borat.y + leftBumpPoint.y,true))
    {
        trace("leftBumping");
        leftBumping = true;
    }
    else
    {
        leftBumping = false;
    }

    if (ground.hitTestPoint(borat.x + rightBumpPoint.x,borat.y + rightBumpPoint.y,true))
    {
        trace("rightBumping");
        rightBumping = true;
    }
    else
    {
        rightBumping = false;
    }

    if (ground.hitTestPoint(borat.x + upBumpPoint.x,borat.y + upBumpPoint.y,true))
    {
        trace("upBumping");
        upBumping = true;
    }
    else
    {
        upBumping = false;
    }

    if (ground.hitTestPoint(borat.x + downBumpPoint.x,borat.y + downBumpPoint.y,true))
    {
        trace("downBumping");
        downBumping = true;
    }
    else
    {
        downBumping = false;
    }
```

where ground is the instance name of a movieclip on the stage

I get this error:

```
1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: ground.
```

Thank you for everyone who read this

Comment: How is `ground` defined?  Is it an instance of a symbol authored in Flash Pro or defined by code?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, ground is just a block, it serves as the platforms for the game, it is a movieclip and is on the stage, with the instance name: ground

Comment: Are you sure that the instance name is ground not the movieclip name, these are two different things, you can name the movieclip ground but then when you drag an instance from the library onto the stage you have to select the instance on the stage and check it's properties to be sure it has the instance name ground.